# AFNetworking HTTP delete use body instead of URL

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I'm trying to send a **HTTP DELETE** request to a *RESTful Django web service* from my iOS app.
I use AFNetworking 2.0 (2.4).

After analysing the `AFHTTPREquestOperation` in the success block of my API call, i found that the body of the request is nil. The parameters URL encoded and sent in the URL.

```
<AFHTTPRequestOperation: 0x10c587940, 
state: isFinished, 
cancelled: NO 
request: <NSMutableURLRequest: 0x10c521ab0> { 
URL: https://anURL.com/connections?data%5Bconnections%5D%5B%5D%5Bid%5D=106 }, 
response: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x10c5c7590> { 
URL: anURL.com/
connections?data%5Bconnections%5D%5B%5D%5Bid%5D=106 
} 
{ status code: 200, headers {
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Tue, 05 Aug 2014 14:07:53 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5, max=100";
    Server = "Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
} }>
```

Now I wonder if it is possible to send the parameters in the body of the request, as done with **HTTP POST** instead of sending them in the URL. Is that possible?

How to do it using AFNetworking?

**How i send atm:**

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

[manager DELETE:host_url parameters:params success:success failure:failure];
```

The body i want to send(its whats in the "params" parameter above):

```
{
    "data": {
        "connections": [
            {
                "id": 92
            },
            {
                "id": 91
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299628/is-an-entity-body-allowed-for-an-http-delete-request

Comment: did u handle the DELETE request. i am stuck in same trouble

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Had same problem. As question is still open, will post answer here. All you need to do, is change HTTP methods, that encode parameters as a query string (by default GET, HEAD, and DELETE). Request serializer has `HTTPMethodsEncodingParametersInURI` property for that. Just set it to GET, HEAD and you are done:

```c
serializer.HTTPMethodsEncodingParametersInURI = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"GET", @"HEAD", nil];
```

Comment: how is it possible to achieve above . i am stuck in same trouble

Comment: saved me, Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Answer provided by @f3n1kc is corrected, but just in case you looking for Swift Version:

```
let manager = AFHTTPSessionManager()
manager.requestSerializer = AFHTTPRequestSerializer()
manager.requestSerializer.HTTPMethodsEncodingParametersInURI = ["GET", "HEAD"]
```